# Set a parameter value out of variables

Tags: jenkins, testng, parameter-passing, testng.xml

In my testng.xml file I have following parameter...

```
<parameter name="env.resources" 
value="src/main/resources/common;src/main/resources/android;src/main/resources/android/test" />
```

I want to change the value for some tests in my jenkins.
I add this line to the maven goals

```
-Denv.resources=${ENV_RESOURCES}
```

and add a textparameter on the top of the build with

```
NAME: ENV_RESOURCES
VALUE : src/main/resources/common;src/main/resources/android;src/main/resources/android/test
```

In the testng.xml I change the line

```
<parameter name="env.resources" value="src/main/resources/common;src/main/resources/android;src/main/resources/android/test" />
```

to

```
<parameter name="env.resources" value="${ENV_RESOURCES}" />
```

If I execute the jenkis job the test works very well. As far as good.

Now I want to add two variables for the parameter value. I try that..

```
value="src/main/resources/common;src/main/resources/${OS};src/main/resources/${OS}/${INSTANCE}" />
```

When I execute the following setting with ${OS} and ${INSTANCE} the test failed.

```
The value : ${OS} can be "ios" or "android" and 
the value : ${INSTANCE} can be "test" or "abnahme" or "produktion"
```

I want only one testng.xml file and want control the parameters via jenkins server.

How can I add this two variables to the testng.xml file?

cheers Jean-Pierre

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are using QAF. If so you can have below paramter in config file;

```
<parameter value="src/main/resources/common;src/main/resources/${OS};src/main/resources/${OS}/${INSTANCE}" />
```

Set `OS` and `INSTANCE` through system property from jenkins.

```
-DOS=android -DINSTANCE=abnahme
```